# Vuefire with Vue 3 throwing Vue.use error

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vuefire

So I created a vue app and imported Vue from vue module but I am getting this error

```
ERROR in src/main.ts:4:5
TS2339: Property 'use' does not exist on type 'typeof import("/data/data/com.termux/files/home/ishankbg.tech/node_modules/vue/dist/vue")'.
    2 | import App from './App.vue'
    3 | import { firestorePlugin } from 'vuefire';
  > 4 | Vue.use(firestorePlugin);
      |     ^^^
    5 | createApp(App).mount('#app');
    6 |
```

I am using typescript in my vue app.
I generated the project using @vue/cli.
I want to use firestorePlugin from vuefire.

I am using Vue3
Here is the source code

```
import Vue, { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import { firestorePlugin } from 'vuefire';
Vue.use(firestorePlugin);
createApp(App).mount('#app');
```

I am not sure what's causing this error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Vuefire](https://vuefire.vuejs.org/) isn't supported in Vue 3 yet.  From the main page:

> **Note:** This version currently supports Vue 2 and Firebase 7. Support for Vue 3 / Composition API and Firebase 8 is on the way.

`Vue.use` is the Vue 2 way of installing plugins. Once Vuefire supports Vue 3, use `app.use` instead of `Vue.use`.  In Vue 3, `Vue` is not a valid export from the `"vue"` package:

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import { firestorePlugin } from 'vuefire';

const app = createApp(App);
app.use(firestorePlugin);
app.mount("#app");
```

Comment: Thank @dan but would you have an idea of how to *Vue.use (app.use)* plugins on individual components.

Comment: @Vixson It doesn't really work that way.  Plugins are basically just global-level functions that run when loading the app, so maybe you need to rethink what you're trying to do.  https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/plugins.html

Comment: Ok @Dan thank, I got that point already. It's just that Migrating from Vue 2 to Vue 3. I got some break changes.
On Vue 2, I normally import plugins I'll need only on the component I'll need it.
Now on Vue 3, I was just lost on how to go about it.